# Python Struct to Unpack like C fread using C structures?

Tags: python, c, numpy, struct, binary

I am struggling to port a snippet of code from C (originally Fortran) to python to unpack the header of a binary file.

The C is:

```
fread(&hdr, hdrSize, 1, modelFile);

alb    = hdr.fd[0];
skrc   = hdr.fd[2];
taud   = hdr.fd[16];
djul   = hdr.fd[40];
deljul = hdr.fd[41];
n4     = hdr.id[3];
n5     = hdr.id[4];
n24    = hdr.id[5];
jdisk  = hdr.id[11];
k4out  = hdr.id[16];
j5     = hdr.id[39];
```

The file has been written using Fortran where, for example, alb is defined as (F10.2) and n4 is defined as (I10).

I tried using both the `struct` module, `numpy.fromfile()`, and `numpy.fromstring()`.  I know the total header size, so using `numpy.fromstring()` I can read the binary (`open(file, 'r+b'`) and generate an array that is significantly longer than expected - This is backfilled with 0.0 which I believe makes sense if the header is a fixed size and the fill data is smaller.

Is the `struct` module the way to go to access the data in the same manner that fread() does?  In the C code, I believe that the `.fd[0]` indicates that we are looking at structure 0?  If so, is that format duplicatable in Python?

Edit:
I am not able to find .id or .fd in the C code, but the original fortran defines them as

```
 REAL*4    FD(80)          
 INTEGER*4 ID(40)
```

The rest of the port from Fortran to C is essentially verbatim, so I would assume that the declarations are identical.

Edit2:
The following appears to be working - in that the variable values are logical.  This is using the struct module.

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r+b') as l:
    headdata = l.read(HEAD_BYTES)
    fd_arr = struct.unpack('f'*80, headdata[0:320])
    print fd_arr[0]
    print fd_arr[2]
    print fd_arr[16]
    print fd_arr[40]
    print fd_arr[41]
    id_arr = struct.unpack('i'*40, headdata[320:480])
    print id_arr[3]
    print id_arr[4]
    print id_arr[5]
    print id_arr[11]
    print id_arr[16]
    print id_arr[39]
```

I will explore using a single format string to see the impact of mixed types within the string.

Comment: It should be easy, but depends on what fd and id are. Can you add the definition of whatever datatype hdr is to your example?

Comment: @JamesRoth Updated using some info from the original Fortran code - the declarations should be identical.

Comment: Note that numpy usually does not align its structured dtypes, while a normal compiler will. Try adding the aligned=True keyword to the dtype definition.

Comment: This seems like exactly what  the `struct` module was intended to do, though alignment issues may get in the way.

Comment: @qwrrty Glad I'm on the right path - I fear that I will have a complex formatting string, i.e. an 80 element float array and a 40 element integer array.  Something like: (`'>' + 'f'*80 + 'i'*40`) or (`'>f80' + 'i40'`)?

Comment: It sounds like you can use a format string like `'>80f40i'` if I'm reading the documentation correctly. I haven't used it myself, but it seems worth a try.

Comment: @qwrrty Edited with a mixed formatting string - Also works with the combined formatting though the offsets naturally differ from the old code.  I wonder if the `array` module would also support this decoding since I know a priori that the data is a pair of arrays.